# knockout.js: Cannot find closing comment tag to match (ko if)

Tags: knockout.js

Saw several questions on SO related to this error.
But I have no tables, `<!-- ko if -->` and `<!-- /ko -->` are in the same tag container:

```
<div id="modelSection">
    <!-- ko if: initPanelBar() -->
    <ul class="panelbar" id="panelbar" data-bind=" foreach: data.Models">
        <li>
            ...
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: initPanelBar() -->
    <div class="no-models">No models to display</div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

In this case i'm still getting an error `Uncaught Error: Cannot find closing comment tag to match:  ko if: initPanelBar()`.
Not familiar with ko.js I don't know what else can be the root of the problem?

Comment: What is inside <li> </li> ?

Comment: It may be caused by poorly structured HTML, so double check your markup inside <li></li> for any markup structure bugs

Comment: @AdamWolski: there are four tens of lines inside li. I'm not sure that there are some issues and this markup contains only spans and divs with data-bind attributes. But of course I'll doublecheck it.

Comment: the problem then is probably with some `</div>` or `</span>` that are misplaced